# Odd email search and sort behaviour

Tags: mac, email

Using Mail in all previous OS I ever used, I click on an email, say from MacWorld.
Then I would sort by From and all the emails from MacWorld would be right in front of me on my screen.

Now when I sort by From, I get all my email From in order, either A to Z, or Z to A -- but nothing to do with MacWorld.

What happened?

MacBook Pro 2.8, 16 GB RAM 10.2.2

Comment: Tap the down arrow